# How to create email alias on the fly with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, email-forwarding

I have been running a small SaaS website that helps home based sales reps to manage their prospects. They generally have email addresses from free services like Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo, and even AOL. If technically possible, I would like to offer these people an email address (more likely an alias address) with this website's domain name.

The scenario in my mind is that the rep is given an online form within the website, she enters her alias address that she would like to have, and then the application saves it to the database by mapping it with her original email address. Whenever there is an email sent to her alias, it will be forwarded to her original email address.

Let's say her original email address is cathy1997@gmail.com, and the alias that she would like to have is cathy@example.com. Whenever cathy@example.com receives an email, the application will forward it to cathy1997@gmail.com.

Primary technologies that I am using on my website are ASP.NET, C#, and SQL Server on a Windows hosting.

Is this technically possible? If yes, is this possible with C#? What would be the simplest way?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You will need to run your own full-featured mail server for this (probably based on linux postfix), and running a mail server is **not at all a trivial undertaking**. There's a lot more involved than just keeping the software running, but also a lot to set up in terms of things like DKIM, rDNS, SPF records, etc, and it's _very easy_ to screw this up in subtle ways such that things _seem_ to work, but a lot of your messages never reach the inbox.

Comment: Also, how will your users handle replies and outbound messages under this scheme, such that their own customers preserve the fiction of talking to the @example.com address?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Joel! Their own customers don't have to preserve the fiction of exchanging emails with @example.com. This will more likely to be a professionally looking forwarding email address with no inbox or storage. Once it is being emailed and it forwards to the real email address, the rest of the conversation will happen through the real email address. For this purpose, do I still have to employ some kind of a full featured mail server? Like you said, it sounds like a huge order.

Comment: You still need mail server software in order to provide forwarding.

Comment: you will need to map this on mail server. Or, have a catch all email, then load email from there and parse the email address, then query database to find out what's the actual email, i.e. my@gmail.com, then forward to it.

Comment: Thanks again, Joel. And, thanks for your input, urlreader. It looks like adding this feature will be more challenging and take much more time than I anticipated. I will postpone working on this feature.